# Выборка внутри одной таблицы

Tags: mysql

В таблице есть 2 поля (product_id и category_id). Как должен выглядеть запрос, чтобы получить только те товары, которые принадлежат всем категориям в условии (список необходимых category_id получаем в виде массива). На скрине выделил желаемый результат выборки при условии category_id = [2,3]

[image: желаемый результат выборки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE category_id IN (2, 3, ...) GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` (count должен быть равен количеству параметров после in)